# How do I access 3rd party lib global objects in Angular 2 apps?

Tags: debugging, angular, devtools

When a library creates an object in the global scope, like `CodeMirror` for that matter, how do I peek into that object in Angular 2?

Say, I am using `ng-codemirror` which uses CodeMirror library, which in turn produces `CodeMirror` object in the global scope. How do I lurk into `CodeMirror.modes` from DevTools when in an Angular 2 app?

Comment: Try `console.log(window.CodeMirror)` and `console.log(window.CodeMirror.modes)`

Comment: I have tried that. `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CodeMirror in your project

```
import 'codemirror';//or what ever the name is of that library.
```

Once you have imported code mirror in your project you should be able to have the global scope you are looking for.